Does it matter if a fuse is on a positive or negative voltage?
I have a power supply with -5V DC output.
Can I use a fuse 5V 0.5A for this -5V rail as if it was 5V 0.5A?
The rail I want to put a fuse on goes into the motherboard.
The motherboard does not have any protection.
It is a Taiwanese Senstron ST-41 (TAO YIN-TCY6 94V) power supply from 1987 used in a Apple 2 clone.

5V   5A
12V  2.5A
-5V  0.5A
-12V 0.5A

To not change the original subject of this question I have posted another one: How to protect a motherboard from an old power supply?

What are the fuses protecting i.e. what components or wiring on the mobo are you hoping will be protected.

There no fuses. I would like to add extra protection on the power supply of an Apple 2 clone.

I'm sorry but it's not clear what you are trying to protect and from what. I mean if the apple clone draws too much current then, it's likely that it has developed a fault already and, fuses won't prevent that happening.

I want to protect the motherboard from a faulty or repaired (but still faulty) power supply by putting fuses on the outputs of the power supply that go into the motherboard.

That just won't help in most scenarios. I mean if the supply generates too much voltage and the apple current is standby/low, then a serious failure of the apple's circuits could develop with just a few hundred milliamps. Faults/failures like this can happen in milliseconds so, a fuse will not have any benefit. What you should do is test the supply to ensure it produces the right voltage.

By the way, question in the title of your post and the question in the body are effectively opposites, such that "yes" to one means "no" to the other, which can make it confusing to read the answers. It's easy enough to reconcile the two upon reading the entire answer, but it makes things more immediately comprehensible when questions in the title and in the body are equivalent.

I have updated the question now.


The fuse does not care if it has + at one end or - (and the
opposite). They do care about AC vs. DC because AC has less tendency
to arc, but that is unimportant at 5V and not much more at 12V.

You generally do not want to fuse a common lead because a break
in the common of a bipolar supply can cause overvoltage on one of the
other supplies.

Fuses are crude devices and drop a lot of voltage in order to get
enough heat to melt the metal element. With fuses in your current
range you may lose ~0.25V of your rail voltage.

Switching power supplies are generally short-circuit protected, so
the fuse should never blow. Overvoltage protection would have to be
built into the power supply. I believe Astec Apple IIe supplies had an SCR
crowbar on the 12V rail. The Taiwan clones may have left them out. I have a supply around here somewhere that I repurposed for powering an emulator.



Yes. Fuses are non-polar.
The fuse is a thermal device.
It contains a material that melts at a relatively low temperature. The heat for the melting process comes from the current (energy) passing through the fuse. The fuse doesn't know and doesn't care what voltage it is at, nor does it know or care about the direction in which the energy is traveling through it. All that matters is that energy goes through the fuse and heats it up.
In engineering terms, this is called an isotropic non-polar component.
Glass tube fuses are usually zinc inside
The thin wire element inside the glass tube of the fuse is typically made of zinc (Zn on the periodic table). Zinc, under room temperature conditions, is a slightly blue, shiny metal. Of interest to fuses is that:

Zinc is brittle at room temperature, but malleable (soft, flexible) when heated. This means that as the fuse approaches its intended limit (in your case, 2 amps), the zinc wire inside is still likely to remain intact (although softer) up until it reaches its melting point and "activates" the fuse by liquefying and thereby breaking the electrical continuity of the circuit.
Zinc has a low melting point (419.5°C) for a metal, while still remaining very conductive. The lower the melting point, the more precise a fuse can be made at any given price point.
Zinc has a lower density than copper, which isn't particularly relevant to anything... I just think that's interesting :)


A glass fuse is a passive device; it is AC/DC and swings both ways. The question is, why would you do this? You are not protecting anything. An over-current protection device (OCPD) like a fuse can only do one thing: protect the wire connected to the load side terminal. That is fine if you have a stiff power source (low impedance), like a utility or battery, capable of delivering significant fault current, resulting in thermal damage to the wire insulation and possible fire.
For example, many 12—and 24-volt power supplies continuously deliver up to 50 amps. No OCPD is required on the DC output because the power supply cannot supply enough current to blow a fuse or thermally damage the wire. The voltage regulators, current limiter, and pass elements cannot physically do that, nor can your 5-volt rails; there is too much impedance in the way. For a fuse to work immediately, within a second or less, it takes a fault 4 to 6 times the fuse rating. The current and voltage regulator in your PSU will shut down as expected.
So yes, you can use the same fuses. Go for it.

I think the power supply is old and with old design from 40 years ago. So I was thinking if I could somehow protect my precious motherboard (I am a collector) from it.

@AntonAndreev I believe the main thing to worry about in that case is noisy power, which fuses do not help with.

Fuses do not care about conventional agreements of people regarding positive or negative voltage.


I have a power supply with +5 and -5 volts output. Can I use the same fuse for both of them rated 5v 2a?

Is this a bipolar power supply with +5, 0, -5 V outputs? If so, you can use the same type of fuse in both supply rails. You'll need separate fuses for the +5 V and -5 V supplies. The fuses don't care what the polarity is.

The fuse I want to insert goes into the motherboard.

Is 2 A the correct rating for both power supply rails? For computer motherboards the supply rails can have asymmetric ratings with the +5 V rail requiring much more current than the -5 V rail so check both rails need the same fuse rating.
For a motherboard full of e.g. analogue op-amp circuits you're much more likely to have a symmetric current rating.

You are correct that different max current is needed so it will be 5A 5V for the 5V and 0.5A 5V for the -5V. Thank you!

One more try. Fuses will not work, but a TVS Diode will. A PSU will not generate enough fault current to operate a fuse promptly, if ever. The goal is to protect your device from overvoltages or transients from the PSU. TVS diodes are passive devices explicitly made for that purpose.
They come in several form factors, such as SMD or axial, and an extensive range of operating voltages and peak power ratings. For example, a Littlefuse 5KP5.0A has a 5-volt 5kW peak impulse rating—enough energy to turn the PSU to charcoal before it lets the overvoltage through. It triggers at 6 volts and clamps the voltage until the surge dissipates or dies trying. Cheap protection at $2



Can I use a fuse 5V 0.5A for this -5V rail as if it was 5V 0.5A?

Yes.


Again, why would you add the fuses? They do not protect anything, and the PSU cannot supply enough fault current to operate them in any amount of time. So, it costs money, serves no purpose, and adds a failure point. I say go for it.
